# Java Android - Making Array of images (same image)

Tags: java, android, arrays, imageview

So I've tried my best but I have not found anything close to what I would like.  I would like to know if this is possible without making 50 instances in my xml file.  What I think i've come close to though:

```
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        bitmapArray.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(Bmp1,(int) image.getX(),(int) image.getY(), bullpick.getWidth(), bullpick.getHeight()));
        bulletArray[i].setImageBitmap(bitmapArray.get(i));
    }
```

I've also tried making an ImageView array of one imageView but that would only leave me with one imageview.  Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: For anyone who doesn't know what I'm talking about, i'm trying to make an array of 50 imageviews of the same image, but anything that would end up with an array of 50 images would be what I'm after. Thanks!

Comment: It seems unclear what you are asking

Comment: I editted the title. Sorry i'm very tired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your image in drawable folder.

Then create a simple loop:

```
ArrayList<ImageView> imageViews= new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage);
            imageViews.add(imageView);
        }
```

This would create an arraylist of 50 imageviews.

Comment: That isn't quite working, is there something else I need, like in my xml? Sorry, i'm new to java and I've never used getApplicationContext